# Will all characters be labelled cheaters once the console is used?

Tags: torchlight

Is that is there anyway to create a character, activate the console and not get flagged as a cheater on all of your characters? I mean, if I create a new character and use the console there for testing purposes, if I log in with a different character, will that character be flagged as a cheater too?

Comment: Hi there.  Questions are unfortunately the only things we actually do here, so it won't be long until somebody comes and edits out all but your last paragraph.  As a side note, hardcore is supposed to be an extra challenge, but a lot of players seem to play the mode without actually wanting the challenge.  Strange.

Comment: 1) you should limit yourself to one question at a time, if you want to have two questions answered, post a separate question 
2) what exactly is your question here about the hardcore? "What's the point of hardcore"? That is extremely opinion based and off-topic for this site.

Comment: You're welcome to bring it up in chat and have a discussion though, once you have the rep. :)

Answer (score 4):

It flags the character, not the account.

[(Source by Runic Staff)](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?p=329635&sid=2e7df2830b959fc56bc99def88789826#p329635)